# Integral depending on a path?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, differential-forms

I need to check whether differential form $\omega$ has, in the domain $G$, such property that it's integral doesn't depend on path. In my exercise: $\omega = \frac{ydx -xdy}{x^2+xy+y^2}$ and $G= R^2 \setminus {(0,0)}$.
So I found the antiderivative, it's equal to $\frac {2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\left(\frac{2x+y}{\sqrt{3}y}\right)$. And my problem is that it isn't defined for $y=0$. So what should I do now to answer my question? Define it for $y=0$? Or maybe it will turn out that this integral depends on a path?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that your differential
$$\omega=Pdx+Qdy:={y\over x^2+xy+y^2}\ dx-{x\over x^2+xy+y^2}\ dy$$
satisfies the integrability condition $Q_x-P_y\equiv0$. Therefore in simply connected subsets $\Omega\subset G$ there exist potential functions $f:\ \Omega\to{\mathbb R}$ with $df =\omega$, or $\nabla f=(P,Q)$.

But there is no global $f:\ G\to{\mathbb R}$ of this sort. For a proof consider the elliptic curve
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr):=\left(\cos t-{1\over\sqrt{3}}\sin t,\ {2\over\sqrt{3}}\sin t\right)\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ .$$
One computes
$$x^2(t)+x(t)y(t)+y^2(t)\equiv1,\quad \dot x(t)=-\sin t-{1\over\sqrt{3}}\cos t,\quad \dot y(t)={2\over\sqrt{3}}\cos t\ .$$
It follows that
$$\int_\gamma \omega=\int_0^{2\pi}\bigl(y(t)\dot x(t)-x(t)\dot y(t)\bigr)\ dt=-{4\pi\over\sqrt{3}}\ne0\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider the limit as $y\to 0$ of your function. This limit depends on whether $x>0, x=0,x<0$ and $y>0,y<0$. Is it possible to define a value anywhere along the line $y=0$ and keep continuity? (Remember that you can choose which arctan to take freely!) If so, how many places can you make a consistent definition?

The question is: once you've made as many consistent definitions as possible, do you have a leftover boundary with a discontinuity you can't fix? If so, you have path-dependent integrals.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to make a consistent function here, because for fixed $x$, if we approach to $0$ with $y$ the limit is different when $y > 0$ and $y< 0$. Am I right? And how to find two paths with the same beginnings and endings, for which the integral is different?

Comment: You can fix it for, say, $y=0,x>0$ but then you're stuck on the other side. For an example of a path, then, draw two semicircles from ,$(-1,0)\to (+1,0)$. The important thing to realize is that $\arctan\pm\infty$ actually has many finite values.

Comment: At least, my guess is that you're stuck; definitely check this! I expect you are.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your $\omega$
$$\omega=\frac{y}{x^2+xy+y^2}dx-\frac{x}{x^2+xy+y^2}dy$$
For integral it has the form
$$\int\bigg(Pdx+Qdy\bigg)$$
which you can test for beeing conservative such as
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$
where
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{\big(x^2+xy+y^2\big)^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{\big(x^2+xy+y^2\big)^2}$$
Which means that the field is conservative and the line integral is path-independent.

**EDIT**

I must have said in the beginning "Assuming that the path is closed..."

and at the end "This is a necessary requirement but not sufficient"

Comment: And the general theorem is that integral is path-independent if and only if $\frac{dP}{dy} = \frac{dQ}{dx}$?

Comment: @Anne yes... it shows that the field is conservative which is sufficient for beeing path-independent.

Comment: No! This is LOCAL! You need to investigate global structure.

Comment: It is a field property... i assumed that the line integral was closed.